# Google engine not loading favicon - react

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, react-helmet

Google does not load my favicon.ico on search results page, it just sets the default react icon.

I am using react helmet, currently the  for it is both in the App component helmet and in index.html in public folder. None which seem to work.

I've read that google wants "stable" favicon url, although favicon is in public folder, served as static. Also they said they are trying to censor potentially inappropriate icons, which has nothing to do with me.

Everything else seems fine on every other engine. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your index.html as well as a minimal version of your App component? However, even if your code is correct now, Google caches search results for awhile, so you might not see the icon update immediately

Comment: You may need to request Google to re-index your site if you want it to update in Google Search sooner.

Comment: The favicon works in other engines, everywhere. And it's been up for a few months now. I'll try that anyways, thanks.

Comment: I've also *heard* that renaming the favicon file may invalidate the cache and also force Google search to update it sooner, but I don't have any proof of that being true :/